# Qt 4.8, canConvert with template

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

i would like to create a converter based on QVariant.

I have make this methode: find()

```
template <typename T>
T find(const QVariant variant, T type) {
  if (variant.canConvert<type>()){
    return variant;
  }
  return T();
}
```

It is called like that:

```
find(qVariant, QString());
```

And after make I've got this error:
No matching function 'QVariant::canConvert()'

Thanks for your help

Comment: it should be `if (variant.canConvert<T>()` ...

Comment: `canConvert`'s template parameter is a type not a variable. It doesn't seem like your function needs the `type` argument at all?

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Have a nice day